# Adding new dependency after running catkin_create_pkg

Tags: ros, catkin-create-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I add a new dependency to my package, after the package has been created?
In my case:
1st step: catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs roscpp
...
Next step: I want to add a dependency to pcl and pcl_ros

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

After editing CmakeLists.txt/package.xml or creating a new package from scratch I get this error when running catkin_make in the root work folder:

CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package pcl.

Set pcl_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for pcl.
The file will have one of the following names:

```
pclConfig.cmake
pcl-config.cmake
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77851/adding-new-dependency-after-running-catkin_create_pkg/) by [Almanakk](https://answers.ros.org/users/6591/almanakk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the CMakeLists.txt/package.xml and see how e.g. roscpp is used there. Play around a bit. Shouldn't be too hard too figure out.

---

Originally posted by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) with karma: 365 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [catmanjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/102936/catmanjan/) on 2022-04-27**:
9 years later, surely there is a better answer than this?